# Select right word in a json object

Tags: javascript, html, json, web

I am new to javascript and to JSON, so please forgive me.
i want to console.log the time of "time"

```
let json = "{ "time":"28-10-2021T23:20:28.402Z", "remoteIP":"192.168.1.1", "host":"www.serveurlardon.com" }";

how to console.log(json.time) <-- dont work // the output i want is 28-10-2021T23:20:28.402Z
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You should escape your quotes or use simple quotes here like so or you'll have some troubles defining a String:

```
let json = '{ "time":"28-10-2021T23:20:28.402Z", "remoteIP":"192.168.1.1", "host":"www.serveurlardon.com" }';
```

Then you need to parse your json

```
const parsedJson = JSON.parse(json);
```

Then you should be able to do

```
console.log(json.time)
```

or

```
console.log(json['time']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man !

Comment: No problem good luck :)